# Why does Lidar to Raster tool in ArcGIS create shifted raster cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, lidar, grass-7.0

I am testing the results of Lidar to Raster with 0.5m resolution with ArcGIS 10.3.1 SAGA-GIS and Grass 7. My LAS File consists of regular spaced points with a 0,5m resolution. No coordinate transformation took place. The resulting rasters are shown in the screenshots below. I created the  LAS Dataset in ArcGIS  by right clicking in the Catalog window in ArcGIS >New>Las Dataset. The Tool LAS-Dataset in Raster was used to produce the raster. The ArcGIS Raster cells are shifted and do not center on the point data from the lidar. The rasters created in Grass-GIS by running r.in.lidar > Export to raster or with SAGA-GIS using the workflow lidar to Pointcloud - Pointcloud to Grid > Export Grid to GTIF both create cells whose center is the lidar point.

Can anyone explain this difference and whether it has an negative effect on the validity of the resulting dataset?

ArcGIS Settings:
[image]

ArcGIS Raster:

[image: ArcGIS Raster]

Grass Raster:

[image: Grass Raster]

Comment: What does [lasgrid](http://rapidlasso.com/lasgrid) from [LAStools](http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools) do in comparison to those other two?

Comment: Rather than asking why they are different, I think you should establish in one question whether one of them gives the correct result.  If so, then your second separate question can be why the other gives the wrong result.

Comment: This question is not broad, it is just incomplete. It was described the full method used in ArcGIS (despite it would have helped more if the screenshot was entirely in English), but not in the other software used. By 'full method' I mean the tools used and their respective parameterization. For example, in [GRASS r.in.lidar](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.in.lidar.html) the default settings are different from ArcGIS'. That could be the cause, if it was the case using a different method. (/cc @PolyGeo).